# Django Rest Framework: How to access the size of a file in the custom written validator for a rest_framework.FileField?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-validation

I don't know how to access the size of the in the validator.

Here is my code

```
# serializers.py
class VideoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """ Base serializer for Video model"""

    video = serializers.FileField(validators=[validate_file_type, validate_file_size])

    class Meta:
        model = Video
        read_only_fields = ('video',)


# validators.py
def validate_file_size(temp_file):
    ...
```

Now I don't know how to access the file size from temp file.

Here. `print(repr(temp_file))` outputs the following.

`<tempfile._TemporaryFileWrapper object at 0x7f8bec3b0438>`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`temp_file.size` returns the size of the file in bytes.

`temp_file` is an instance of [django.core.files.TemporaryUploadedFile](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/files/uploads/#django.core.files.uploadedfile.TemporaryUploadedFile)

Comment: the hyperlink does not exist.